# Html input type number min attribute does not validate for decimal number with negative sign

Tags: html, validation, input, numbers

I am validating my input type number tag with min attribute set like so

```html
 <input type="number" max="-1.3" step="0.1" />
```

But when i type -1.4 or -1.5 and soon on it does not input it.

**MORE INFO**

If I use the arrow keys or click the up-down buttons than it works.

Comment: Because `-1.5` and `-1.4` are less then `-1.3`

Comment: can you specify the number range you want to validate

Comment: oh yes my bad. i meant max attribute. glad you pointed out @Alex.

Comment: actually its less than any number below -1.3 @Lakindu

Comment: is it solved now?

Comment: @Lakindu nope but if use the arrow keys or the up-down keys it works.

Comment: for me, it seems fine, i ll edit your question with a snippet, it seems not increasing to me when trying from arrow kets and up down button.. number won't go upwards (-1.2, -1.1...)